# What is the origin of "tall tale"?

Tags: phrase-origin

A *[tall tale](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tall+tale)* is a folkloric story that is generally wildly exaggerated and told for the amusement of the listeners.  Tall tale tellers usually claim some sort of personal involvement in the story.  I was curious about the origin of the phrase itself, and in the course of poking around, I found that *tall* in this phrase means *exaggerated*, so "tall tale" means an "exaggerated story."

What I can't seem to find is where this term originated.  It seems to be sometime in the middle to late 1800s in the US, but who coined this term?  Was it a famous author?  Did someone publish a book of tall tales around that time?

(More specifically, the argument revolves around whether or not Mark Twain was responsible, although if it's not him, then who?)

EDIT:
According to Etymology Online, [tall](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=tall%20tale&searchmode=none) "meaning 'exaggerated' (as in **tall tale**) is Amer.Eng. colloquial attested by 1846."  (Now I will look to find where it is attested in 1846.)

Another Edit:
An additional bit of interest is that a tall tale is considered folklore, and this word (folk-lore) was very famously coined by William Thoms in 1846.

Comment: I always thought that the phrase was a reference to Paul Bunyan, THE "tall tale", but I don't have any references to back that up.

Comment: Were tall tales originally oratorical tales, which then spread much like rumors do, resulting in their exaggerated nature? If so, it might be very difficult to pin down when the first usage of "tall tale" was used. Could the term have been commonly spoken prior to its being written?

Comment: Using *tall* with *tale/story* is trivial metaphorical usage that doesn't really justify searching for "first recorded use". Both forms were probably repeatedly re-coined anyway, in speech and writing.

Comment: @Fumble My interest justifies it for me.

Comment: @Eri Tall tales are like a storytelling genre, but the exaggeration is intentional (unlike a rumor) and part of the style of telling. I don't know if it was used in spoken English a long time before it was written, but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: @Kit: I'm not saying the usage isn't interesting, just that I can't see how you could meaningfully identify a "first use". Here's one from 1855 that has slightly archaic meaning and/or grammar... http://books.google.com/books?id=prY5AQAAIAAJ&q=%22tall+tale%22&dq=%22tall+tale%22&hl=en&ei=6MUIToqtB8_wsgaVgrG5DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAzgU

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That 1855 reference is from the introduction (page xi) of a reprint of [an omnibus of two books](http://www.harmonieparkpress.com/Products/117-further-revelations-of-an-opera-manager-in-19th-century-america-the-third-book-of-memoirs.aspx), one from 1855 and one from 1890. It's impossible to tell when the introduction was written.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I don't disagree. My substantive point is simply that the expression was around long before the 1920s when it really took off. I'm not trying to get a badge for finding "first use"; I've repeatedly said I think that's a bit of a lost cause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the link you posted in 2011 shows to be dated 1968, Google has since improved their OCR readings, thankfully! http://books.google.it/books?id=prY5AQAAIAAJ&q=%22tall+tale%22&dq=%22tall+tale%22&hl=en&ei=6MUIToqtB8_wsgaVgrG5DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y

Comment: @Mari-LouA - why did you delete your answer?

Comment: One is tempted to suspect that Paul Bunyan had something to do with popularizing the term, though apparently his name was not well known prior to about 1910.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possible early example from *The American Museum* for [February, 1788](http://books.google.fi/books?id=s_xGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22tall%20tale%22%20OR%20%22tall%20tales%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AKT1UIn0NcKF4gTFvYDAAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22tall%20tales%22%20&f=false):

[image: Here are a maiden's coaxing eyes: these pretty tall-tales always give the tongue the lye ; for whenever their fair mistress fays, " Ah go away !" these little things always cry out " stay !"]

A 1752 printing of William Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar* includes *tall-tale*:

[image: You speak to Cæsca, and to such a man, That is no fleering tall-tale.]

[Modern copies](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/julius_caesar/full.html) render this as:

> You speak to Casca, and to such a man
>   That is no fleering tell-tale.

So the [1752](http://books.google.com/books?id=T7k8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22tall%20tale%22%20OR%20%22tall%20tales%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MaT1UPe7COqL4gSnkYG4Ag&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBzgK) was probably a typo, but could the mistake have been influenced by the existence of *tall-tale*?

The same applies to this [1714](http://books.google.fi/books?id=r-ANAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA81&dq=%22tall%20tale%22%20OR%20%22tall%20tales%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eKv1ULqiBuqK4ATMhYHoDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22tall%20tale%22%20&f=false) printing of *The Life and Death of Richard III*:

[image: Let not the Heav'ns hear these Tall- tale Women Rail on the Lord's Anointed.]

Answer (score 3):

[Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tall%20tale&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) show usage since around the right time

[image]

and the term definitively has its place in American short story, which was one of Mark Twain's playgrounds. However searching through Mark Twain's [writings](http://www.online-literature.com/twain/), gave no results so I wonder if it could have been him.

Wikipedia references points to several interesting sites; tall-tale [postcards](http://www.wisconsinhistory.org/whi/results.asp?search_type=advanced&search_field1=creator&search_field1=&keyword2=tall-tale) starting at 1908.

Comment: The first two instances I could find of "tall tale" in Google books, 1879 and 1881, were [both](http://books.google.com/books?id=79kEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA310&dq=%22tall+tale%22&hl=en&ei=SpIITtSRN9StgQfC2o2eDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDAQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22tall%20tale%22&f=false) [Canadian](http://books.google.com/books?id=XelMAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22tall+tale%22&hl=en&ei=hpMITsqcLMHFgAflhN3FDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22tall%20tale%22&f=false).

Comment: Here's one from London, 1839 http://books.google.com/books?id=soAEAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA2-PA201&dq=%22tall+tale%22&hl=en&ei=RpUITqrIHsmdOvL--d4M&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22tall%20tale%22&f=false

Comment: @Unreason: that's a typo for tell-tale (although the printed words are clearly *tall-tale*.)

Comment: @Peter, yes, agree, just was thinking about it myself

Comment: Thanks for the link for searching Mark Twain's body of work — that's a great resource!  I guess you are right that he probably didn't come up with this phrase.  That's a bummer; I had lunch riding on it.

Comment: @Kit, but if he did, there is at least an equal chance that he would use it in his writtings for some newspaper, which the above link does not search (?)

Comment: @Unreason Well, then. There's still hope for it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The more common expression originally was **tall story**. Here's an [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tall%20tale,tall%20story&year_start=1850&year_end=1930&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showing how the two variants stacked up before the US started getting seriously attached to **tall tale** in the 1930s...
[image: .]
...and [here's](http://books.google.com/books?id=ubg5AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA424&dq=%22tall%20story%22&hl=en&ei=WKMITqGpEtDDswa6ooy4DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tall%20story%22&f=false) a snippet from the Athenaeum magazine showing that even back in 1870, we Brits recognised the metaphorical **tall** as American. But as other NGrams show, the US **tall tale** usage didn't really dominate until the 1940s.

I don't think there's anything remarkable about using "tall" to mean "exaggerated". As to why US usage massively favoured coupling it with **tale** rather than sticking with the established **story**, I think Americans just like the partial alliteration better, so it caught on.

**LATER** as mentioned elsewhere, I don't think it's meaningful to look for a "first use" of the **tall tale** variant. However, I do suspect that an important factor in its sudden rapid rise starting in the late 1920s may be the [Paul Bunyan](http://my-ecoach.com/modules/custombuilder/popup_printable.php?id=11801) stories which became incredibly popular around then, and were invariably refered to as **tall tales** (the fictional character Bunyan was always depicted as a big, tall man).

Comment: Thank you for the "tall story" information, but to be clear, I am specifically interested in the *first* use of "tall *tale*."

Comment: @Kit: Per my comment on your question, and the last paragraph of my answer, I really don't think it's meaningful to look for a "first use" of either variant. You'll find "Tall-tale women" in Shakespeare's *Richard III*, for example. Such transparent metaphorical usage would probably be repeatedly "re-invented" by people who didn't know it as a "stock phrase".

Comment: @Fumble I have only found "tell-tale women" in *Richard III*.  I haven't yet found any reference to "tall tale" prior to the late 1800s (except for typos and OCR errors), and while it might not be meaningful to you to find the first use of the word, it is meaningful to me.

Comment: @Kit: I stand corrected re "tell-tale", but I still don't think I can help with your search for a specific early usage. The term was clearly around for generations before it suddently took off in the US within a decade or two in the 1920s.

Comment: For future posts including NGrams, do you mind adding a link to the search you used? I was wanting to take a peek at what happened [post-1930](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tall+story%2Ctall+tale&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and it would have been helpful to see the parameters of your search. No biggie; but it would be nice. :)

Comment: @MrHen: Done. I don't know why I never thought to do that before, but in future I'll try to make a point of including the link as well as the chart itself. I only chose that particular date range because I wanted to show what was happening *prior* to the big rise.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: OED has ***tall** = grandiloquent, magniloquent; high-flown; esp. in **tall talk*** first recorded 1670. The more specific *exaggerated, highly coloured. U.S. colloquial* sense is first recorded 1846 as *"our Arkansaw friend's stories smelt rather tall"*. But I still think "first use" is a fairly meaningless concept for this particular usage.

Comment: Ahh, I found that entry too in the 1919 OED edition. I think I'm onto something more interesting now, but Kitfox really wanted to know *who* first created this term , and that I'm afraid, is impossible to find out.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: To repeat - I really do think it's not a matter of saying it would be *difficult/impossible* to identify who first used ***tall*** with the exact sense under consideration. It's actually *meaningless* - like trying to identify the first "human being" (whose parents were obviously *not* "human", if you want to go down that pointless route). It's easy to imagine a smooth transition from *1374: Quick, prompt, ready, active* thru *1450: Comely, goodly, fair, handsome; elegant, fine* and *1529: doughty, brave, bold, valiant*, followed by later nuances as specified above. It's a continuum

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that. And you are right that  the meanings of words evolve, and continue a long progression. I did say that your answer had the soundest explanation, but I believe mine will prove to be at least interesting (if albeit meaningless), I've done a fair bit of reading/skimming/scanning online, my answer's nearly done. I'll throw myself to the arena tomorrow.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I eagerly await the chance to be the lion to your Christian tomorrow! :~)

Comment: You can begin mauling...

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=CUjQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA475&dq=Emma%20E.%20H.%20Specht&hl=en&ei=bNkMTtG5CNPegQempJThDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBQ#v=snippet&q=tall%20tales&f=false) 1873 reference via Michael Quinion's [discussion](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-tal2.htm) of the phrase. It's from a story called *Gentle Hortense; or, the Maiden’s Leap* by Emma E. H. Specht:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=CUjQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA475&dq=Emma+E.+H.+Specht&hl=en&ei=bNkMTtG5CNPegQempJThDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBQ#v=snippet&q=tall%20tales&f=false]

Comment: This is the link to the snippet http://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/moajrnl/acg2248.2-12.005/375:15?rgn=full+text;view=image;q1=tall+tales

Answer (score 1):

I fell into this looking for the origin of “tall tale”. I was pleasantly amused by the smooth flow of answers & gentle comradery. Everyone so short & precise.

I have difficulty making long stories short, or would it be making tall stories short or small?

I believe the German ‘toll’ has a clear
relationship with the Bearlá na Sassenach (Saxon’s Anglish)word ‘tall’. Tall & toll are homonyms.

Central & upstate NYers say Merry Merry got merried. NYCers say Merry Mary got married (Merree mare-ee got Mah(r)reed.)

You all know that English is an Eater of Tongues, right? 
I believe you are all right, & together have flushed out the pheasant in the blush. Or bloomin’ Bush.  It’s tail fathered out like a fan.

Tall, tell, tale are so close it is easy to see them morph 
back & forth into each other though because at an 
esoteric level they are related.

English being an obviously young, prominent & the 
dominant language in the world at this time.

English gobbles up words like a chicken, grain. I foresee a spreading of a form of Chinglish dialect being absorbed 
into our relatively young English, like all the others it has souped into its stew. However the Chinese might feel. On 
many levels the proliferation of English & its baby brother, American, a sign the world is indeed shrinking.

I believe you are all correct, IMHO, however I disagree 
about the word Telltale. A telltale is an informant, a 
tattletale rat. It implies someone who is a gossip or loose lipped. In the UK  & Nothern Ireland they are called
Supergrass. It is supposed to be derived from ‘snake in 
the grass’ or traitor.

The Irish or Gaelic word for ‘tall’ is ‘ard’, meaning ‘high’ 
as in Ard Righ(ree) or High King. Probably the root of our word Art as the Latin is a derivative of the Celtic, an older civilization the Romans grew to conquer & absorb.

So tall & high are synonyms. There is also a term (sorry, 
I’m an hereditary keeper of the lore)High Tales, which indicates it is not going to be a ‘low’ tale, & possibly 
will be of important & intrinsic value.

High Tales are wondrous & magical. Tall tales are amusing 
& hopefully enjoyable. What tale are we all serving?

Pin the tail on the... Do tell.  Love & Light. Gra agus Solas.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "tall" comes from German [toll](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/german-english/toll) meaning *amazing*, *incredible* or *extraordinary*.

> ADJ.
>
> 1 [UGS.] (großartig) great [INFML]; fantastic [INFML]; (erstaunlich) amazing; (heftig, groß) enormous [RESPECT]; terrific

Comment: If that were the case then there would be instance of "toll tales" or "toll stories", I think. Have you found any such things?

Comment: @MattЭллен but what about its pronunciation? The word *tall* can be pronounced like *toll* i.e. **/tɔːl/**. Is the term *tall* derived from German?

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's true. I suppose *toll* could have been converted to *tall* before ever being written, but such speculation is not particularly helpfull without evidence.

Comment: Google translates http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/toll as *great*. It kinda fits, but yes, a little more evidence would have been nice, but it's not so poor as to merit a downvote IMO

Comment: Lots of [German immigrants](http://home.comcast.net/~owen.rutz/rutz_genealogy/German_Immigration.htm) in the US during the 19th century: *German emigration to the United States occurred in three major waves. The first, which came mainly from southwestern Germany in the years **1845-1855**, consisted of 939,149 men, women, and children*

Comment: @Mari-LouA but the phrase has been around since long before then. Hugo places it as far back as 1714.

Comment: @MattЭллен he also says *tall-tale* could've been  typographical errors for *tell- tale* What does OED say for "tall tales"? Presumably Etymonline carries the same dates, which is 1846. Isn't it wonderful how one small comment can actually lead to a possible answer?

Comment: Interestingly, German *toll* appears to be cognate with English *dull,* an adjective one certainly hopes not to encounter describing a story.

Comment: @Mari-LouA there were many German speakers in the US before the beginning of the 19th century.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Germantown was founded outside Philadelphia [in 1683](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germantown,_Philadelphia).  Also the 1714 instance seems probably to be a misspelling or variant spelling of "tell-tale."

Comment: @phoog I posted a very long and detailed answer based on the German/Scandinavian immigration supposition, it was later self-deleted because of the lack of support it generated. After three years, I might consider resurrecting it. I might...