# Does "kowtow" have racist connotations?

Tags: connotation

Just wondering if this had its origins in a "questionable' time and should be avoided. For example, if it were used during a time of predjudice against Chinese laborers, or used to refer to their behavior, then it might be said to have questionable origins.

Even if those roots are unknown to most people, like the word 'gypped' it could have prejudicial undertones.

Comment: Most people would not know the origin (Chinese) yet use the word to mean submissive to authority anyway. That usually means there is no racism implied.

Comment: What time do you expect was "questionable"?  The *OED* finds the first use in print in 1804.

Comment: The close reason given is "primarily opion based", though the [is 'white lie' racist?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254672/does-the-term-white-lie-have-racist-connotations?rq=1) question is just as opion based and did quiet well.  If this question can attract good answers I think it has a chance.  It would help if had more research into the issue.

Comment: kowtow means *bow down head* - how racist could that be?

Comment: @BlessedGeek *Not at all*, to *quite a lot*. :)

Comment: I think this question needs to be moved to the Chinese language forum.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I would love to get some Chinese perspectives, but am more interested in how it is used in English, since it has a different proper meaning in Chinese.  As has been [http://m.phys.org/news/2016-03-paper-plos-firestorm-referencing-creator.html] highlighted recently there are lots of ways usage can evolve to have different meanings in different cultures.

Comment: @beroe I don't know that it's used very much in English, except in an ethnic context. By the way, [About reopening questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7839/142322): I'm not exactly sure how to address the *primarily opinion-based* (POB) charge, but question-closing on ELU is an invitation to redraft, not the end of the road. I've contributed an answer that *I* think meets ELU's standards for objectivity, so I don't think your question is POB. Then again, it's my own answer :) . If you come up with an edit to satisfy those who voted to close, let me know and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence for the answer and explanation. I am somewhat surprised by the close votes, since if you look in the side bar, similar questions abound. (Does uxorious have sexual undertones? White lies, etc.) I was just curious and your answer is fairly complete, although I am left hanging a bit. Don't have the enthusiasm to try editing a straightforward question to thread the needle of editorial approval. Regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kowtow),

> Kowtow ... is the act of deep respect shown by prostration, that is, kneeling and bowing so low as to have one's head touching the ground.

With reference to its origins, reading *before* to mean *in front of*, not *predating*:

> In Imperial Chinese protocol, the kowtow was performed before the Emperor of China.

The wikipedia article also offers some notes on modern usage, including in induction ceremonies and in other contexts, such as:

> In extreme cases, the kowtow can be used to express profound gratitude, apology, or to beg for forgiveness.

Negative references include the [May Fourth Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_Fourth_Movement):

> an anti-imperialist, cultural, and political movement growing out of student demonstrations in Beijing on May 4, 1919, protesting against the Chinese government's weak response to the Treaty of Versailles, especially allowing Japan to receive territories in Shandong which had been surrendered by Germany after the Siege of Tsingtao.

Modern colloquial usage sees the word in a more derogatory light:

> **Kowtow** *verb*
> 1 Act in an excessively subservient manner
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kowtow)
>
> **Kowtow** *Intransitive verb*
> 2. To show servile deference.
> [- The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kowtow)

The Free Dictionary offers several synonyms, of which the following are among the less unprintable in polite society:

> grovel, court, flatter, lick someone's boots

You ask in relation to the origins of the word:

> Does “kowtow” have racist connotations?

The simplistic answer is *no*.

The origins are rooted in imperial China (or before), performed by Chinese to Chinese, so it does not originate from racist roots. However, to *kowtow* to someone, whether physically and metaphorically, speaks of a vast difference in status. Although modern usage is split between honour codes and derogatory references, it is often (possibly *always*) derogatory when not offered voluntarily.

In particular, in the absence of an honour code as context, saying that someone *kowtows* to someone else doesn't normally carry the literal sense of *prostration*. At best, it carries the connotation of *grovelling*.

In light of all this, the fuller answer is that because the term is recognisably ethnic, using *kowtow* instead of (say) *grovel* does carry some racist overtones, particularly when applied to someone interacting with a person of a different ethnicity.

Comment: Re-reading this, I really appreciate your answer @Lawrence. It follows the full arc of the origins and implications and comes to a satisfactory conclusion.

Comment: @beroe You’re welcome, and I very much appreciate your kind feedback.